# Why does the method change the input parameter (array), despite the fact that I copy it inside the method?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm new to Java. I have a method that should return a new modified array. But after executing the code, the array that is the parameter also changes. Please explain where I am modifying the original array. How can this be fixed? I am desperate because I don’t understand where I am passing the link instead of the value.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int[][] inputArray = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        System.out.println("Original array:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(inputArray));
        //Display
        //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

        System.out.println("Array after delete line:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((removeLine(1, inputArray))));
        //Display - ok
        //[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0]]


        System.out.println("The original array after using in method:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(inputArray));
        //Display
        //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0]]
        //I don't understand this.
    }

    static int[][] removeLine(int k, int[][] inpArray) {

        //I copy in resultArray to keep unchanged inpArray.
        int[][] resultArray = new int[inpArray.length][inpArray[0].length];
        System.arraycopy(inpArray, 0, resultArray, 0, inpArray.length);

        //I change resultArray.
        for (int i = k; i < resultArray.length - 1; i++) {
            resultArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(resultArray[i + 1], resultArray[i + 1].length);
        }
        Arrays.fill(resultArray[resultArray.length - 1], 0);

        //I return resultArray.
        return resultArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a _deep copy_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
//I copy in resultArray to keep unchanged inpArray.
int[][] resultArray = new int[inpArray.length][inpArray[0].length];
System.arraycopy(inpArray, 0, resultArray, 0, inpArray.length);
```

to:

```
// I copy in resultArray to keep unchanged inpArray.
int[][] resultArray = new int[inpArray.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < inpArray.length; i++) {
    resultArray[i] = new int[inpArray[i].length];

    for (int j = 0; j < resultArray[i].length; j++)
        resultArray[i][j] = inpArray[i][j];
}
```

Apart from the fact that you're not creating an actual copy of the area, you're also setting every subarray of `resultArray` to the length of the first element in `inpArray`. Most arrays are going to have subarrays of differing lengths though, so you should give each subarray  an individual length.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really works. I correctly understood that I did not copy the values, but copied the links to nested one-dimensional arrays when I executed arraycopy?

Comment: Yes, the array was still made of the subarrays of `inpArray`. Now that you mention it though, you should be able to replace the second for-loop with `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy` does not do a deep copy; rather it does a shallow copy. In other words, it copies the references and therefore `System.arraycopy(inpArray, 0, resultArray, 0, inpArray.length);` behaves as follows:

```
inpArray[0] and resultArray[0] refer to the same object
inpArray[1] and resultArray[1] refer to the same object
inpArray[2] and resultArray[2] refer to the same object
```

and so on...

which also means

```
inpArray[0] == resultArray[0] is true
inpArray[1] == resultArray[1] is true
inpArray[2] == resultArray[2] is true
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!